# Conditional Buttons True and False React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, create-react-app

[image]

I believe that the error may be here ...

```
{options.map((option) => (
          <button
            key={option}
            className={`${myAnswer === option
                ? "true"
                : myAnswer !== option
                ? "button"
                : "false"
            }`}
            onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(option)}
          >
            {option}
          </button>
        ))}
```

How do I make sure that when the user clicks the correct answer the True class (appears) and when he clicks the wrong answer the False class appears on other buttons. Would it be possible after clicking the first time to leave the buttons disabled, so that it is impossible to change the answer?

- - - > [DemoCode](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-app-8b48o) < - - -

[image]

Comment: I would recommend against nesting multiple ternary statements if you can avoid it, it becomes unreadable very quickly.

Comment: @DBS How can I do this

Comment: Well in this particular case, I would just always have the "button" class, and just add a "correct" or "incorrect" class as well. That should also simplify your CSS, depending on how it's written (as you can just change the color without duplicating all of the other styling)

Comment: @DBS I made the update in the code and put Correct (Class correct) and Not-Correct (Class not-correct), I put an example in the question so that it is possible to see how it is. Even if you click on the wrong answer, the style continues to erode that of the right answer, would you be able to do just one click and then all the buttons are frozen? When the user clicks on the answer it automatically shows the answer if he got it right or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper function for that like so:

```
const isAnswerCorrect = option => option === myAnswer;

...

{options.map(option => (
    <button
       key={option}
       className={isAnswerCorrect(option) ? 'correct' : 'not-correct'}
       onClick={() => this.checkAnswer(option)}
    >
        {option}
    </button>
))}
```

Comment: Could you help me create this function? I'm a newbie yet and I don't have much knowledge

Comment: @André updated with an example. You could do a swith case or multiple conditionals in that function.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible after clicking the first time to leave the buttons disabled, so that it is impossible to change the answer?

Yes, we can disable the actions in different ways. In the below example I've used `isSubmitted` in order to understand whether to perform the action on click of the answer or not. We can also disable using `css` as well.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const data = {
  question: "Dummy Question?",
  answers: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  correctAnswer: "B"
}

const Quiz = () => {
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    
  const onSelectAnswer = answer => {
    if(isSubmitted) return;

    setIsSubmitted(true);
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
    setIsError(data.correctAnswer !== answer);
  }
  
  const getAnswerClass = (answer) => {
    if(!isSubmitted) {  
      return "";
    } else if(data.correctAnswer === answer) {
      return "correct";
    }
    return isError ? "incorrect": "";
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{data.question}</h3>
      {data.answers.map(answer => (
        <p key={answer} 
          className={getAnswerClass(answer)}
          onClick={() => { onSelectAnswer(answer)}}
        >
          {answer}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.correct {
  background: #5aad5a;
}

.incorrect {
  background: #fa7f7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Here, for simplicity I have just used one question. But this can be extended as per your requirement.

Comment: That's what I wanted. But I don't know where to start now to change my code, as I said before, I'm a newbie

Comment: In fact, Some functions from the snippets can be used as it is. 
May be if you create a sandbox, we can help you with where you are struggling.

Comment: [LINK CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-app-8b48o). I am trying to see how I can solve this I am completely lost now lol. You created the Fuctional Component and I'm using Class already starts there. Each question enables another button for the next question and at the end the total number of correct answers appears ... Many doubts ...

Comment: I have updated the `MainQuiz` component, you can find that [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-app-forked-83h7e?file=/src/components/MainQuiz.js).